# Convert excel data to json using VBA-JSON library

Tags: json, excel, vba

I'm try to convert the excel data to json using the VBA-JSON library that grab from https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON but Fail
I want convert the target Market Country column into JSON Array `"CountryCode": ["MY","TH","CN","US","IN"]`
End up with this result `"CountryCode": "MY,TH,CN,US,IN"` by using the VBA-JSON library

How to convert the excel column to json array =  `"CountryCode": ["MY","TH","CN","US","IN"]`

My excel data as below:
[image: excel data]

```
    For Each cell In rng

        mainContainer("id") = cell.Value
        subContainer("lang") = "en"
        subContainer("value") = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        subArray.Add subContainer
        mainContainer.Add "Brand", subArray
        mainContainer("CountryCode") = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        items.Add mainContainer
    
         Set mainContainer = Nothing
         Set subContainer = Nothing
         Set subArray = Nothing
         i = i + 1
    Next
    jsonfile.WriteLine ConvertToJson(items, Whitespace:=2)
    jsonfile.Close

    Set fs = Nothing
```

My current result is like this...
[image]

Comment: Try splitting the country codes into an array, e.g. `Split(cell.Offset(0, 2).Value,",")`. This will give you an array, which should serialize in the format expected.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, it get the result I need. Thank you so much.